# incomplete kwargs for format()

Tags: python

I'm trying to format a string with incomplete kwargs as below:

```
input is like "{key1} {key2} {key3}"
output will be like "value1 value2 {key3}"
```

I try below,

```
>>> "{key1} {key2} {key3}".format(key1='value1', key2='value2')
```

but got following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'key3'
```

Any idea on what's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to fix this,

1. Double escape the pattern

   ```
   >>> "{key1} {key2} {{key3}}".format(key1='value1', key2='value2')
   ```
2. Or pass `{key3}` as the value

   ```
   >>> "{key1} {key2} {key3}".format(key1='value1',key2='value2',key3='{key3}')
   ```